# Template specialization for a class member function in order to not use increment operator on bool

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, boolean, increment

In my application I use a class to flag elements that are inidicated by positive numbers (see code below). The template parameter of `class Stamp` is usually an `unsigned integer`. The advantage of flagging with a counter is, that `clear()` usually executes fast on huge vectors, as one increment of the counter invalidates all flags. Currently, only in my unit tests, I use `boolean` as template argument. Using `boolean` comes closest to the naive implementation of flagging numbers. But the increment operator for `boolean` is deprecated and will soon vanish from the standard and the compiler complains already about deprecation (not knowing that the part it's complaining about wouldn't even be executed in case of `boolean`). How would you specialize method `clear()` for the `boolean` case? I could not get it right, I tried it by just adding the the following definition.

```
template<>
void Stamp<bool>::clear() {
    std::fill(stamped.begin(), stamped.end(), false);
}
```

Now the compiler complains about multiple definitions of `clear()`. How is template specialization done right in that case. And what other possibilities do I have to fix this class in modern c++?

```
template <class T> class Stamp {
private:
    std::vector<T> stamped;
    T stamp;

public:
    Stamp(unsigned int size) {
        stamped.resize(size, std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
        stamp = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    }

    ~Stamp() { }

    void clear() {
        if (stamp < std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) {
            stamp++;
        }
        else {
            std::fill(stamped.begin(), stamped.end(), std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
            stamp = std::numeric_limits<T>::min() + 1;
        }
    }

    void unset(unsigned int index) {
        assert(index < stamped.size());
        stamped[index] = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    }

    void set(unsigned int index) {
        assert(index < stamped.size());
        stamped[index] = stamp;
    }

    bool isStamped(unsigned int index) const {
        return stamped[index] == stamp;
    }
};
```

EDIT:
Using the answer of @Constructor I could come up with a method specialization by adding another definition of clear() to the header like this:

```
template<>
inline void Stamp<bool>::clear() {
    std::fill(stamped.begin(), stamped.end(), false);
    stamp = true;
}
```

This is kind of ugly but it actually works. Neither compiler nor tests choke on it.

Comment: Full (or explicit) function template specialization is not a template. So you should treat it like a normal function (and not to violate ODR): 1) place the declaration in a header file and the definition in some cpp file OR 2) mark it as `inline`.

Comment: So it actually _is_ possible to only specialize on one method. Thanks, I'd vote for this if I could :-P

Comment: I have added [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464654/3043539).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full (or explicit) function template specialization is not a template. So you should treat it like a normal function.

There are two possibilities not to violate [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (One Definition Rule) when you are working with functions or methods of classes:

1) place the declaration of the function/method in a header file and its definition in some cpp file:

```
// Stamp.h

template<>
void Stamp<bool>::clear();

// Stamp.cpp

template<>
void Stamp<bool>::clear()
{
    std::fill(stamped.begin(), stamped.end(), false);
    stamp = true;
}
```

2) mark it as `inline` and place its definition in your header file:

```
// Stamp.h

template<>
inline void Stamp<bool>::clear()
{
    std::fill(stamped.begin(), stamped.end(), false);
    stamp = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't specialize member functions without specializing the whole class. It is a silly language limitation that exists for historical reasons that don't (in my opinion) apply any longer.

Instead of specializing the whole class, you can make `Stamp<T>` inherit from `StampBase<T>` which you then specialize.

```
template <typename T> class StampBase;

template <typename T> class Stamp : public StampBase<T> {
    // Code goes here!
    void clear() {
        StampBase<T>::clear_impl();
        // Rest of code.
    }
};

template <typename T> class StampBase {
protected:
    void clear_impl() { /* T is NOT a bool */ }
};

template <> class StampBase<bool> {
protected:
    void clear_impl() { /* T IS a bool */ }
};
```

Comment: `set` and `isStamp` should be specialized too

Comment: While I appreciate your corrections, the goal of my answer was to show that the base class should contain only that code which needs to be specialized for bool. In addition, I'm writing this on a laptop with a 768 pixel vertical resolution. I literally can't see both the question and my answer at the same time.

Comment: Actually it was possible to only specialize on one method by using the hint to the keyword `inline` of @Constructor. So neither compiler nor tests choked on adding another definition of `clear()` with `inline` to my header-only implementation. However, your solution looks nice :-)

Comment: Thanks @Gruffalo for the hints to `set` and `isStamped`. Setting `stamp=true` in the specialization of `clear` fixes the issues you've seen. However, writing a full specialization (at least for the methods you mention), would be more optimal.

Comment: There is no "silly language limitation" as "one can't specialize member functions without specializing the whole class" in C++ ([since C++98 at least](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43295ea2981d3483)).

Comment: I call this a "silly language limitation" because the only reason it is not allowed is because the standard says so. I believe MSVC does allow this as an extension.

Edit: Full specialization of function templates is allowed, which is what your answer does. *Partial* specialization isn't, which I consider a silly and artificial limitation.

Comment: 1) There is no word *partial* in your answer. 2) Obviously, the question is asked about the full specialization.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, the compiler creates the fully specialized class Stamp<bool> in any case (at least when I use it). So defining a special clear() method (which is a 'partial' definition to be used in a full specialization) gives me a full specialization in the end. I can't see the limitation here.